# Hadoop: FileSystem.get method throws IOException

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am newbie to Hadoop. I am trying to run below simple code but keep getting IOException with message being `No FileSystem for scheme: file`. I am running a single node Hadoop 2.7.0 on Ubuntu. I suspect it's a configuration issue. Any quick help will be highly appreciated. I have searched StackOverflow but not have not found a suitable answer.

```
// Check if a file exists 
public boolean exists() throws IOException {
    boolean isExists = false;       
    try{
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        Path newPath = new Path(hdfsRoot,file.getName());
        isExists = hdfs.exists(newPath);
        hdfs.close();           
    }catch(IOException ex){
        // log exception and then re-throw
        throw ex;
    }
    return isExists;
}
```

It's the FileSystem.get method that's throwing IOException.

Comment: can you show me hdfsRoot and file.getName() value?

Comment: hdfsRoot points "hdfs://localhost:9000" and file.getName is a.txt. But the exception is thrown from FileSystem.get method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Check if a file exists 
        public boolean exists() throws IOException {
            boolean isExists = false;       
            try{
                FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:9000"),new Configuration());
                Path newPath = new Path("/test.txt");
                isExists = hdfs.exists(newPath);
                hdfs.close();           
            }catch(IOException ex){
                // log exception and then re-throw
                throw ex;
            }
            return isExists;
        }
```

Note - hdfsRoot should be `hdfs://localhost:9000`  and file.getName() should be your file name. mean your file location should be hdfs://localhost:9000/test.txt

let me know if not work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changed code as per your suggestion but I am still getting IOException but this time with "No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs" .

Comment: Somewhere I read the exception can be thrown if required jar files are not in CLASSPATH. I have a number of jar files in the classpath. I don't suspect this to be a classpath issue. Some configuration issue I think.

Comment: above code is work for me. you have some other problem. is your hadoop working? , if yes then add all the respective hadood jar on classpath

Comment: jps command shows ResourceManager, DataNode, NameNode, SecondaryNameNode, NodeManager.

Comment: mean your hadoop is working fine. add all the respective jar

Comment: add a test.txt in hdfs by hdfs dfs -put test.txt /   and the execute the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87734/discussion-between-shashi-and-krish).

Comment: I think the problem was with disk space on my virtual machine. After resized the boot disk of my VM, things started working for me. Along with that I also moved HDFS initialization code to constructor of my wrapper class. Krish's answer helped me. Hence marking his answer.

Comment: I am not getting what the actual problem ? you said that "after resized the boot disk of my VM, things started working for me." mean above code is working fine. continue with chat If I solve your problem.

Comment: I think the actual problem was due to low disk space on the machine. Once disk space was increased, Hadoop commands started working.